# how to renew Okta token when claims change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, okta, okta-auth-js

So I have a working react app using oauth (using okta) and I have an issue.

When I change my claims in the authorization server the app does not see this until the token expires or I logoff and login again.

But when refresh the page(F5) I the `getUser()` function returns the correct claims but the token is not updated.

Is there a way to tell the okta client to fetch a new token ?

I am using okta-auth-js.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found `getWithoutPrompt()`
https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js/blob/master/README.md#tokengetwithoutpromptoptions

Which enables me to fetch a new token when I detect the change with the `getUser()` function

```
authClient.token.getWithoutPrompt({
  responseType: 'id_token', // or array of types
  sessionToken: 'testSessionToken' // optional if the user has an existing Okta session
  scopes: [
    'openid',
    'email',
    'profile'
  ],
  state: '8rFzn3MH5q',
  nonce: '51GePTswrm',
  // Use a custom IdP for social authentication
  idp: '0oa62b57p7c8PaGpU0h7'
 })
.then(function(res) {
  var tokens = res.tokens;

  // Do something with tokens, such as
  authClient.tokenManager.setTokens(tokens);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  // handle OAuthError or AuthSdkError (AuthSdkError will be thrown if app is in OAuthCallback state)
});
```